# CRM Plugin not able to do web request in third party DLL (After ILMerge)

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow, crm, ilmerge

I'm developing a CRM Workflow plugin to call a web server. I'm using my own external DLL for the actual webcall (using HttpClient) in that plugin that I merge using ILMerge so that it's included in the plugin dll. This works, as I can succesfully use a method from the DLL once I run the workflow without it failing.

However, when I try to call a method in the DLL that performs a web request, it fails with a nullpointer. If I copy the code in it's entirety to my plugin dll, the web request does not fail. Both DLL's are signed (I've tried both with the same key and different keys).

What am I missing? I can post code if people want, but as I said, the same code works if I copy it in to my plugin source directly, and the external API DLL works when I use it in a console project. There are no settingsfile or anything related to the api or plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If your own external assembly references HttpClient, you should also include the *System.Net.Http* assembly in ILMerge. The merged assembly should contain your plugin assembly, your external assembly and the System.Net.Http assembly.